# Existe algum tipo específico para senhas que não seja String no .Net?

Tags: .net, string, segurança, senhas

Eu vejo muito comumente o uso de `string`s para armazenar senhas na memória do programa, não só no .Net, mas em todas as linguagens de programação que já usei.

A princípio, eu não vejo um problema nisso. Mas como eu sei que o ecossistema do .Net é ENORME, me surgiu essa curiosidade: Existe algum tipo otimizado para guardar senhas, ou o `string` é o único? E se existe, vale a pena? Ou `string`s já são suficientes?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @luiscubal Acabei de ver esse tipo. Se tiveres experiência com esse tipo e puder responder as duas outras perguntas, ficarei grato.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O tipo [SecureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) é descrito pela documentação da seguinte forma:

> Representa texto que deve ser mantido confidencial. É encriptado para
>   privacidade quando está a ser usado, e apagado da memória do
>   computador quando deixa de ser necessário.

Este tipo implementa a interface `IDisposable` e é através do método `Dispose` que se indica que deve ser eliminada da memória.

Várias classes do .NET que lidam com passwords, incluindo o PasswordBox do WPF, incluem [métodos ou propriedades](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.passwordbox.securepassword%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) que utilizam esta classe.

O objetivo desta classe é impedir que as passwords sejam guardadas no disco (*swap*) e tornar mais difícil (embora não impossível) que um atacante com acesso à memória do computador consiga descobrir qual o valor da password.

Naturalmente, esta classe só tem interesse se a password nunca sequer chegar a estar disponível como uma `string` ou `byte[]` convencional.

Também relevante: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141203/when-would-i-need-a-securestring-in-net (em inglês)

Comment: Acho que entendi... só vale a pena se você cria a senha caractere-por-caractere, por exemplo, já que transformar uma string em `SecureString` não seria útil já que você já tem uma string "insegura" na memória. É isso?

Comment: @AndréLeria Na prática, sim. No entanto, se já tiver um API que mantenha a string em memória, pode na mesma ter interesse converter em `SecureString`, caso a `SecureString` seja usada por muito tempo. Nesse caso, o coletor de lixo poderá talvez libertar a string e deixar a `SecureString` viva pelo resto do tempo. Mas o ideal é tê-la em SecureString o tempo todo.