# Como, quando e por que usar "SecureString" no C#?

Tags: c#, .net, string, segurança, senhas

Uma vez ouvi falar sobre a classe `SecureString` do C# e me pareceu interessante, então acho que é conteúdo interessante o que pode render boas respostas de profissionais mais experientes.

Algumas perguntas a serem feitas poderiam ser:

- Alguém já trabalhou com essa classe, ela costuma ser usada em grandes
  projetos?
- Quando seria realmente necessário usar essa classe e do que ela
  protege?
- É mais recomendado seu uso para que tipo de projeto: ASP.NET, WPF,
  Windows Forms?

Comment: Murilo, segue o [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141203/when-would-i-need-a-securestring-in-net) original no SO em Inglês.

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada, mas seria bom ter uma resposta aqui em português. Até tem na MSDN, mas aqui a galera explica de forma bem legal

Comment: @Rodrigo traduz e coloca uma resposta.

Comment: Desta forma, recomendo este post do SO em português: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/7425/59662

Comment: Bom link,  porém vou manter minha pergunta, pois estou perguntando especificamente sobre SecureString, na questão citada outra pergunta levou a ela. Não acho que seria duplicada.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Alguém já trabalhou com essa classe, ela costuma ser usada em grandes projetos?

Não, não conheço uma boa porção de grandes projetos para afirmar. Não sei se isso tem relevância. Ou o recurso é útil ou não, se ele é usado em projetos grandes ou pequenos não vem ao caso.

[O próprio .NET usa bastante](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/securestring.cs,77d68ea938f47705,references). Todos esses lugares consideram que um texto em condições seguras é importante em seu contexto.

> Quando seria realmente necessário usar essa classe e do que ela protege?

Basicamente ela garante que será usada em um contexto bem restrito e será apagada tão logo quando possível, além de não permitir que ela saia do âmbito da memória da aplicação. Obviamente ela é criptografada.

Mas ela não é completamente segura, afinal ela precisa ser manipulada e nesses momentos fica descoberto. Ela dificulta tentativas ingênuas de acesso indevido. Ajuda bastante o próprio programador não divulgar o dado em algum lugar por seu próprio deslize.

Muita gente não sabe que ao final da aplicação os dados ficam lá na memória, eles não são apagados e podem ser visualizados por terceiros com o conhecimento adequado. Mesmo durante sua execução é possível acessar todos os dados mesmo de fora dela. É muito fácil pegar tudo o que está na memória. Em uma máquina comprometida, seja por um *hacker*, seja por uma pessoa com acesso privilegiado que seja mal-intencionada.

Se a intenção é proteção total, esquece. Em geral usa-se apenas para dados que realmente precisam ser protegidos na memória, como senhas, número de cartão de crédito e coisas assim. Se todo o resto da cadeia tiver falhas, não adianta muita coisa.

> É mais recomendado seu uso para que tipo de projeto: ASP.NET, WPF, Windows Forms?

Não importa, use quando precisa dessa segurança. O WPF possui um controle [`PasswordBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.passwordbox?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0) que usa o [`SecureString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0) internamente, então elimina um ponto de insegurança onde o dado pode ser capturado.

Parece que no Mono ela não é tão bem implementada, mas isso pode mudar logo com o projeto pegando partes do [.NET Core](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40671/101).

Tem uma [pergunta que trata disso aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/122454/101).

[Artigo da Microsoft sobre o assunto](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/shawnfa/making-strings-more-secure?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). E a [continuação](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/shawnfa/securestring-redux?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

[Não é mais recomendado o seu uso](https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0001.md).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).