# Como é feita e armazenada a criptografia de uma SecureString?

Tags: c#, .net, string, segurança, criptografia

A classe `SecureString` é utilizada para representar um texto que deve ser mantido como confidencial na memória (senhas, números de cartões, saldos e etc.), e realiza a sua correta exclusão da memória quando o referido texto não for mais necessário.

- Como é feita essa criptografia? Como é armazenada a chave?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Só usá-la não adianta muito. E achar que ela dá total segurança é bobagem. Leia mais em [Como, quando e por que usar "SecureString" no C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/164465/101).

A implementação é detalhe, então varia dependendo do *runtime* usado e da versão dele e não deve se prender a ela. Então não tem como responder a pergunta feita. E esta é a resposta.

Mas posso dar algumas informações:

- o [.NET Framework](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/securestring.cs,77d68ea938f47705) tem uma forma complexa de decidir o que fazer e delega para outras partes do *framework* cuidar da criptografia, usa muito código de baixo nível e API do Windows.
- o [.NET Core](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src/System.Security.SecureString) delega para outra biblioteca, dá para tentar achar a implementação. [Também](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/SecureString.cs,77d68ea938f47705) e a [parte específica para Unix](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/SecureString.Unix.cs,77d68ea938f47705).
- o [Mono](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.Security/SecureString.cs) usa o `Encript()` dele próprio, tem que ir lá ver como este método faz.

Pelo que entendi usam chaves internas do *framework* ou do sistema operacional, que é mais seguro.

Comment: Estava pesquisando sobre como um anti-cheat pode proteger dados importantes na memória, e lembrei que o SecureString seria um bom ponto de partida para me basear.

Comment: Não existe *anti-cheat* eficaz em software cliente. E é por isto que o SS também não é seguro.

Comment: Sim, concordo que nada substitui um servidor autoritativo. Porém, há ocasiões em que o custo desta implementação se torna impeditivo, ou mesmo quando não temos tempo suficiente para implementá-la. Como exemplo, posso citar um advergame voltado para uma campanha publicitária com um curto tempo de vida. Dentre as técnicas que penso em empregar seria a criptografia das variáveis e sua constante troca de endereços na memória.