# Por que é melhor usar char[] do que String para senhas?

Tags: java, string, segurança, char, senhas

Utilizando Swing, o método `getPassword()` do `JPasswordField` retorna um array de caracteres `char[]` ao invés de retornar uma `String` como o `getText()` (que por sinal está descontinuado).

Não devo utilizar `String` para armazenar senhas? Por que em `char[]` seria melhor? Questões de segurança?

Comment: Essa é uma das perguntas que eu mais queria ver aqui no site. Obrigado =D

Comment: Relacionado, mas para .NET: [Existe algum tipo específico para senhas que não seja String no .Net?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7423/2541)

Comment: Também: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/164465/101

Answer (score 14, accepted):

É sobre segurança. Se uma informação fica mais tempo que o necessário na memória tem mais chance da aplicação ser comprometida e alguém com acesso à máquina possa pegar a senha.

*Strings* são imutáveis, você não pode escrever sobre ela, se quiser mudar o conteúdo de uma *string*, tem que criar outra *string* nova e descartar esta antiga. O problema é que o descarte de fato só ocorrerá quando o *garbage collector* entrar em ação, e pode levar muito tempo.

Um `char[]` é mutável, então em qualquer momento você pode zerar o conteúdo dele. Mesmo que não seja coletado na hora, ao ter os valores zerados a senha não fica exposta mais tempo que o necessário (ou seja, uma ínfima fração de segundo).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Então, pela lógica, após utilizar a senha devo zerar o array?

Comment: Se quer algo seguro, sim, claro que isso é só um dos aspectos da segurança. Não quer dizer que está 100% seguro porque fez isto, mas que é uma das coisas que evita certo comprometimento.